# Many to Many relation in EF made without links to the entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I would like to shift from the common pattern in many to may relation using implicit joint table and instead I want to use the joint table explicitely and implement a kind of lazy load of many-to-many dependent entity.

This is framed by the design of disconnected sets, where the objects graph is passed via http to the application server. On the server I update just keys, not entities.
The reason for that: if I try to save the same entity defined with different instances of an entity model, I get the concurrent scenario error.
Instead, I don't want to pass on object, rather I just want to pass the joint table with IDs.

```
Class
-------
int ID
List ClassStudent

Student
-------
int ID
List ClassStudent


ClassStudent // this type must be explicitely defined in the model
--------------
StudentID
ClassID
```

Is it possible to define such configuration with FluentApi?

The common scenarion is using types:

```
Student
---------------
int ID
List Classes

Class
----------
int ID
List Students
```

I don't need this beacuse of concurrent changes.
Need to help with fluent API. I've tried many cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. All you need is to configure a composite PK for the `ClassStudent` and two unidirectional `one-to-many` relationships (`Student -> ClassStudent` and `Class -> ClassStudent`).

Something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ClassStudent>()
    .HasKey(e => new { e.StudentID, e.ClassID });

modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
    .HasMany(e => e.ClassStudent)
    .WithRequired()
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.StudentID);

modelBuilder.Entity<Class>()
    .HasMany(e => e.ClassStudent)
    .WithRequired()
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.ClassID);
```

Comment: Thank you! It saved me. I get ClassStudent with foreign keys. Now, when I get IQueryable<Class>.Including<ClassStudent>, the property is empty. Should I load ClassStudent table separately? Or there is another way to fill the property using fluent api configuration?

Comment: You are welcome. I don't quite understand the last comment/question though. There is nothing more special needed. Executing something like `var classes = db.Class.Include(e => e.ClassStudent).ToList();` does load `ClassStudent` property. Similar for `Student`s.

Comment: Yes, just've forgotten to seed the data.It's ok.